# MongoDB fulltext search not using index

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing, mongodb-query, full-text-search

We use mongoDB fulltext search to find products in our database.
Unfortunately it is incredible slow.
The collection contains 89.114.052 documents and I have the suspicion, that the full text index is not used.
Performing a search with explain(), nscannedObjects returns 133212.
Shouldn't this be 0 if an index is used?

My index:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "textIndex",
    "ns" : "search.products",
    "weights" : {
        "brand" : 1,
        "desc" : 1,
        "ean" : 1,
        "name" : 3,
        "shop_product_number" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "german",
    "background" : false,
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

The complete test search:

```
> db.products.find({ $text: { $search: "playstation" } }).limit(100).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "TextCursor",
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 133212,
    "nscanned" : 133212,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 133212,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 133212,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 1041,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 105,
    "server" : "search2:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't nscannedObjects actually be 100 if there was efficient index usage?

Comment: I don't know mongoDB's internal implementation in detail, but only using indexed fields, it should be 0 since no documents are scanned. Probably they will check all documents in the result again to exclude results which were added because of similar stems. But 133212 documents and only 100 really match?

Comment: Your limiting by 100, that is why n is 100

Comment: Correct. But it's about nscannedObjects / nscanned and if the index is used or not. I only used limit(100) to make it a little faster since there is no sorting...still needs about 20 sec.

Comment: Actually this is confusing me a little due to my own tests. It seems under my own testing if limit is correctly applied to the index then scanned objects should be 100 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the question you asked:

> *".... The collection contains 89.114.052 documents and I have the suspicion, that the full text index is not used ...."*

You are only "nScanned" for 133212 documents. Of course the index is used. If it was not then 89,114,052 documents ( because this is English locale and not German ) would have otherwise been reported in "nScanned" which means an index is not used.

Your query is slow. Well it seems your hardware is not up to the task of keeping 1333212 documents in memory or otherwise having the super fast disk to "page" effectively. But this is not a MongoDB problem but yours.

You have over 100,000 documents that match your query and even if you just want 100 then you need to accept this is how this works and MongoDB does not "give up" once you have matched 100 documents and yield control. The query pattern here finds **all** of the matches and then applies the "limit" to the cursor in order just to return the most recent.

Maybe some time in the future the "text" functionality might allow you do do things like you can do in the aggregate version of [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) and specify "minimum" and "maximum" values for a "score" in order to improve results. But right now it does not.

So either upgrade your hardware or use an external text search solution if your problem is the slow results on matching over 100,000 documents out of over 89,000,000 documents.

Comment: If that's the way MongoDB works, it's ok. This was not clear by reading the documentation. So regexp-searches will work the same way, right? Probably we have to accept that mongo text search is not practicable for this amount of documents. The hardware is up-to-date. Even our second search server was incredible slow with SSDs.

Comment: @TobiasK. Unless your $regex searches are anchored to be beginning of the string then you are at least expecting full index scans. But here is the point. No amount of fast disk will ever compare to fitting the working data in memory. So it is RAM you want, or sharding in order to split the working data across servers with the RAM to cover. The same applies for external text solutions, though they will generally be more optimized.

Comment: I totally agree. But >200 GB RAM are not that affordable at the moment. For our new backend we will switch to elasticsearch since mongodb fulltext search is not that powerful so far. Maybe in the future. I just try to find a way to get it fast enough until the new backend is ready.