# avoid scanning every match with full-text search on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, database

It is well known that mongodb full-text search ($text) operator, scans all the matches before returning.

[MongoDB fulltext search not using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825551/mongodb-fulltext-search-not-using-index)

[Performance issue on MongoDB text search and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910806/performance-issue-on-mongodb-text-search-and-limit)

Is there any way to avoid it?

And I'm not willing to make the question unclear but I seriously wonder why it scans every matching document before returning the results.